# how to check if both parameters are set in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say I have a executable bash file `script.sh`.

I want to use it as

```
./script.sh p1 p2
```

`p1` and `p2` are two necessary parameters for this command. If either one of them is missing, the command should fail.

So I need to check them before go on executing further in `script.sh`. How could I check both of them are set?

updated:

I tried this:

```
# this is a comment line
if [ -n "$1" ] || [ -n "$2" ]; then
    then echo 'haha'
fi
```

but got:

```
./_scp.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./_scp.sh: line 3: `    then echo 'haha''
```

Comment: You have two `then`, and missing last `;`, you only need `if [ -n "$1" ] || [ -n "$2" ]; then echo 'haha'; fi`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In POSIX shell, if you only want to check that two parameters was set, try:

```
if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
  echo >&2 'Need 2 parameter'
  exit 1
fi
```

If you want two non-empty parameters, you should use `-z` instead of `-n`. `-n` tests if length is non-zero, `-z` tests if length is zero.

```
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo >&2 'Need 2 parameters which are not empty'
  exit 1
fi
```

---

With `bash` (and `ksh` and `zsh`), you can use:

```
[ -v var ] && echo var was set
```

to check whether variable `var` was set or not.

```
$ [ -v var ] && echo var was set
$ var=
$ [ -v var ] && echo var was set
var was set
```

Note however that `$1`, `$2` are not variables, they are a different type of parameter called *positional parameters*. `[ -v 1 ]` to check whether the first positional parameter is set does work in `zsh` or `mksh`, but not in `bash` nor `ksh93`.

Answer (score 6):

You can make them fail the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
: "${2:?} ${1:?}"
#If either one of the above is unset or null the 
#script will have already exited with a meaningful
#diagnstic message written to standard error.
```

The shell exits with error and the message is generated automatically: exactly what it says is shell dependent, but it usually looks like this:

```
(set --; ${1:?})
sh: 2: 1: parameter not set or null
```

...where *first_colon_delimited_field:* is `$0`, next is `$LINENO`; followed by *var_name*, and finally *diagnostic message.* You've probably seen similar messages in the past.

You can get specific about the diagnostic message:

```
(set --; ${1:?Hi there!})
sh: 3: 1: Hi there!
```

Also, it's an inline, implicit test. If the targeted parameters *are* set and not null *(or possibly null if you drop the `:`colon from `:?` the parameter expansion syntax)*, they expand normally:

```
(set param; echo "${1:?This better not be empty!}")
param
```

And this, like other forms of modifying [parameter expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), can be applied to other types of parameters than just your positionals:

```
param= bash -c '
    printf "Sure hope this works...\n" "${param:?Not a chance!}"
    echo ... but what about me\?
'   newzero
echo "RETURN: $?"
```

...which prints to my terminal...

```
newzero: line 1: param: Not a chance!
RETURN: 127
```

The optional diagnostic message is itself an expansion - whatever it expands to is what the shell will write out to stderr. I almost always use it for the `--help` message when I add option parsing to a script. I just make a little function and pass it the numbered parameter I expected when I encounter an issue:

```
#script and more script
help(){ eval "\${$param:?\$(cat)}"; } <<HELP
Usage [ and the usual ... ]
HELP

while getopts ....
do    case $opt in ($myopts) :;;
      (*) param=$OPTIND help;;esac
done
```

Comment: My bad when forgetting this standard way.

Comment: @cuonglm - It's not *as* standard as `test` - you've got my vote already. I just like that you can make stuff blow up with a brace or two.